# Is there any possible way to remove bios password on dell latitute 7420?

Tags: bios, dell-latitude

Is there any possible way other than to open up the laptop? I want to remove the password.

Comment: I take it you *forgot* the password?

Comment: Yes. I _forgot_ the password.

Comment: then there's no way other than resetting CMOS - which I would assume would require opening the laptop

Comment: Damn. What do I have to do after I open the laptop?

Comment: reset/clear CMOS - refer to the user manual of the *laptop* - or google search `clear cmos on dell latitude 7420` (seems you do NOT have to open the laptop - however, this may not clear the BIOS password)

Comment: You could try https://bios-pw.org, but that's very unlikely to work on newer laptops. CMOS reset isn't guaranteed to work either as newer machines have more advanced ways of storing the password.

Comment: Have you tried reseating the BIOS battery (the round one when you open the bottom).

Comment: The advice by Dell is to contact their Support.

Comment: @cup apparently newer dell laptops do not have a BIOS battery - they "reserve 5% of the battery" instead - seems like removing the main battery would do the trick, except I bet the battery isn't (easily) replaceable

Comment: Haven't heard of that one before - just in case it is one of the older modles, Dell CMOS batteries are never the easiest to remove - sometimes they are hidden under the main battery and LED cluster.  Sometimes you have to dismantle the whole machine to get to it.  If it does have a CMOS battery wait at least 30-45 minutes for the system to discharge after removing both batteries.  If it is one of the slot in ones, make sure you dont break the back of the holder.  Once that is broken, you've got a very expensive brick.

Comment: If it has a CMOS battery you could unplug it, and wait for the CMOS battery to be exhausted but that could take months or years so it isn't very practical, but you wouldn't have to open your laptop.

Comment: @Destroy666 I tried bios-pw.org, but I don't think they provide password for the latest dell laptops. None of the password there worked.

Comment: @JaromandaXI think I have one of the newer versions of the laptop. Is there no way to reset the bios password?

Comment: @cup I have not, I'll try that later. But I am not sure if it will help.

Comment: I'm afraid you might be out of luck then. Resetting CMOS is unlikely to do anything, you can try ofc though. It didn't work on my 2-3 years older HP laptop, for instance, I just had to bruteforce the password. BIOS is much more secured nowadays. Contacting the support also won't help likely, unless you want a "send it to our technicians for a high price" kind of reply.

Comment: @Destroy666 Aww man